# crear y Escribir en un archivo.txt En java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de crear un documento, quiero que cada vez que se ejecute el programa el archivo me guarde cada uno de los numeros del 0 al 4 sin embargo solo me guarda el ultimo, creo que debo sacar el FileWriter del for pero no se me ocurre como.

Gracias por la ayuda

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                FileWriter fileRoute = new FileWriter("newFile.txt");
                fileRoute.write(
                        "Elemento numero=====>" + String.valueOf(i)
                );
                fileRoute.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Usa ``fileRoute.append("")`` y en el FileWriter agrega un segundo parámetro con true además del archivo, para mantener los datos anteriores.

Comment: Sería mejor que instancies y cierres el FileWriter fuera del for, además de pasar el segundo parámetro

Comment: Hola, si sacar el close y el Filewriter me funcionó, gracias

Comment: Como te comentan mas arriba, agregando un true como segundo parametro al filewriter seria la forma correcta de tener archivos que se puedan extender. Si luego mas adelante en el codigo quisieras agregar algo mas al documento, podrias hacerlo de esa manera, sino simplemente te sobreescribiria el archivo.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        FileWriter fileRoute = new FileWriter("newFile.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            fileRoute.write("Elemento numero=====>" + String.valueOf(i));
        }
        fileRoute.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
      }
    }
```